# Assigning IDs to form a hierarchy in R

Tags: r

I have a heap of data for different agencies. They are listed by number of staff respondents at each level in the hierarchy (level1-5) with level one being agency name and level 5 being the smallest work unit. I need to assign ID numbers to each of these responses in the hierarchy so that for example I can tell that ID321 is a branch under ID257 which is a group under agency ID 110.

Is there a way I can do this in R?

I would like to use this to form tree maps of each agencies org structure.

Thanks!

Comment: Please give us an example of your data. How many units are at each level of hierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

You can use data.tree to form tree structure of your agencies:

```
# simulation of the group of agencies/companies data (5 levels)

df <- structure(list(var1 = c("Comp1", "Comp1", "Comp1", "Comp1", "Comp2", 
"Comp2", "Comp2", "Comp2", "Comp2"), var2 = c("Divis1", "Divis1", 
"Divis1", "Divis2", "Divis1a", "Divis1a", "Divis1a", "Divis1a", 
"Divis2a"), var3 = c("Dept1", "Dept1", "Dept1", "Dept1c", "Dept1a", 
"Dept1a", "Dept2a", "Dept2a", "Dept1b"), var4 = c("Sec1", "Sec2", 
"Sec2", "Sec3", "Sec1a", "Sec1a", "Sec2a", "Sec2a", "Sec3"), 
    var5 = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "I", "J")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
9L))

#    var1    var2   var3  var4 var5
# 1 Comp1  Divis1  Dept1  Sec1    A
# 2 Comp1  Divis1  Dept1  Sec2    B
# 3 Comp1  Divis1  Dept1  Sec2    C
# 4 Comp1  Divis2 Dept1c  Sec3    D
# 5 Comp2 Divis1a Dept1a Sec1a    E
# 6 Comp2 Divis1a Dept1a Sec1a    F
# 7 Comp2 Divis1a Dept2a Sec2a    G
# 8 Comp2 Divis1a Dept2a Sec2a    I
# 9 Comp2 Divis2a Dept1b  Sec3    J

# convert dataframe into tree structure
df$owner <- "Owner"
df$pathString <- with (df, paste(owner, var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, 
                         sep = "/"))
df_n <- as.Node(df)
plot(df_n)
```

Output:
[image: Structure]